# How to check what the newest file is in a GitHub repository inside a bash script?

Tags: git, github

I have started working on a Bash script to help automate some aspects of a personal project, part of which involves a USB ROM programmer. As part of this script, I want to be able to automatically update the firmware if necessary. As someone has a GitHub repository of the update software, I'm wanting to use that to grab the update file my software needs.

However, I need a way to know what the latest version of the update software is so I can grab it, as each version is committed as a separate file. Looking at the repository from a web browser it is easy to see what the latest file is, but how would I go about this from a bash script without having to download the entire folder from the repository beforehand?

(If more information is necessary, the repository is Kreeblah/XGecu_Software and the exact folder I care about is /Xgpro/10)

Edit: Rephrasing myself based on what @torek said, what I mean is that I need to find out what the latest commit is, then check if that commit added any files to a specific folder so I can download it if it exists.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "newest file" in a Git repository. Repositories consist of *commits* (plus some auxiliary things like tags and branch names and so on) and it's the *commits* that have date-and-time-stamps on them. Files, if they exist at all, exist courtesy of being contained within some commit. Commits don't contain folders either: they contain files, plus the commit metadata (including the commit's timestamps).

Comment: This means you need to re-formulate your question. Are you looking for the commit with the highest timestamp? Are you looking for the last commit in some named branch, and then want to see what the timestamp is on that commit? Define what you're looking for in terms of what a repository actually *has*, before you try to find out how to get that.

Comment: @torek Well the newest file is always part of the latest commit, so in this case the two are the same. So I guess I'm trying to say that I need a way to find what the latest commit is and what file in this specific folder was added in said commit, if any.

Comment: OK. So, now we're getting somewhere. The thing is, "latest" could be by *time-stamp*, or could be *branch-tip*. Each commit gets two date-and-time stamps, which are under control of the person making the commit, but default to using the time set on their computer. If their computer clock is wrong, one or both time-stamps might be weird. If time-stamps are the crucial item, though, that's probably what to look at.

Comment: Alternatively, it's very easy to get the hash ID of the *last* commit on some named branch, because that's precisely what a branch name produces. From that hash ID, you can extract the commit's metadata, including the author or committer time-stamp; using that hash ID, you can have `git archive` extract the entire commit (as a tar or rar archive), or a given file from the commit.

Comment: Given that the repository is on GitHub, you can also use GitHub's extensions—their web server responds to various `curl`-generated queries—to compare the latest commit to its parent(s), or get information about the commit. Or, of course, you could just clone the repository and use `git fetch` to update your local clone: much easier, but takes more storage.

Comment: So, by time-stamp would be "relative (to the person committing) latest" while by branch-tip would be "absolute latest", if I'm interpreting what you said correctly.. I'd want to know what the absolute latest commit is, so by branch-tip. ... and just as I comment this two other comments come in. :/

Comment: Okay, so, the main point of this is to not grab the entire repository as I don't need the entire repository taking up space on my computer. So I'm probably going to want to look up the GitHub curl API. Then, somehow using that, figure out what file I need to grab, grab it, `unar` it twice (once for the RAR and once for the EXE), and update.